# three.js converting equirectangular video to cubic panorama video?

Tags: three.js

Came across this example here

http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_panorama_equirectangular.html

Was wondering if the same thing is possible if the source was video with equirectangular projection, not still a still image?

Comment: Yes, if the source is video with equirectangular projection, you can use three.js to render it as a texture on the inside of a sphere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. And this example shows how:
http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_materials_cubemap_dynamic2.html

Comment: Thanks, but you are actually creating 3d objects which is pretty cool!! in itself. But can I simply load an equilateral projected video such as https://vimeo.com/49771436 instead of the still image?

Comment: You'll have to map that video into the sphere. http://stemkoski.github.com/Three.js/Video.html Then for converting to cubemap use the cubecamera.

Comment: Thanks. for whatever reason using video makes it crawl almost to a standstill. Only getting about 2 fps with my 720p video .mp4 source. Was really excited after seeing your demo with the still image but may have to opt for a flash based solution